# Python program errors

Tags: python

I'm writing a program that needs to find all pairs of initial conditions (x0,y0) where the x goes extinct first and plot them.the equations are:

> j=x-y+100 and
>   i=x+y-100

and the constraints are from (0,200) in both the x and y directions.

my code looks like this:

```
for x in range (0,201):
for y in range (0,201):
    c=0
    i=x
    j=y
while (x > 0 and y > 0):
    i=x-y+100
    j=x+y-100
    c=c+1
if i==0:
    plot(i,j)
if c==50:
    break
```

and my error says:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):                i=x-y+100
  File "", line 1, in <module>

  File "/tmp/tmpqTzdAj/___code___.py", line 3, in <module>
    exec compile(u'for x in range (_sage_const_0 ,_sage_const_201 ):\n    for y in range (_sage_const_0 ,_sage_const_201 ):\n        c=_sage_const_0 \n        i=x\n        j=y\n        while (x > _sage_const_0  and y > _sage_const_0 ):\n            i=x-y+_sage_const_100 \n            j=x+y-_sage_const_100 \n            c=c+_sage_const_1 \n        if i==_sage_const_0 :\n            plot([i],[j])\n        if c==_sage_const_50 :\n            break
  File "", line 11, in <module>

  File "/app/sage/sage-6.1.1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sage/misc/decorators.py", line 692, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "/app/sage/sage-6.1.1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sage/misc/decorators.py", line 537, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **options)
  File "/app/sage/sage-6.1.1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sage/plot/plot.py", line 1134, in plot
    G = _plot(funcs, *args, **kwds)
  File "/app/sage/sage-6.1.1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sage/plot/plot.py", line 1236, in _plot
    funcs, ranges = setup_for_eval_on_grid(funcs, [xrange], options['plot_points'])
  File "/app/sage/sage-6.1.1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sage/plot/misc.py", line 132, in setup_for_eval_on_grid
    range_steps = [abs(range[1] - range[0])/(p-1) for range, p in zip(ranges, plot_points)]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Are you sure you're getting that error on this lines? Can you post the relevant code(The line numbers you see on the traceback)?

Comment: Where is `plot()` coming from?

Comment: This is not the full code that causes the error, as you never actually call `len()` on anything in the code that you have posted.

Comment: where is `len( )` coming from?

Comment: yea @utdemir: lines 1,3,692,537,1135,1236,102.... which confuses me

Comment: @alecxe: i have no idea what that even means. i havent had anyone teach me this so im just winging it. i've looked up all i can and its just not helpful

Comment: @unixer: i dont know!!!!

Comment: @AlexThornton i promise this is the full code. i have no idea why it is telling me that

Comment: Can you fix the indentation levels and add the complete traceback?

Comment: @arry ok, you should have `import` statements in the beginning of the script - provide them, thanks.

Comment: @arry paste the code for the `plot()` function.

Comment: @Fury yea sure hold on.

Comment: @alecxe ok but im not sure what those are so it'll take me a min to work that out

Comment: @AlexThornton this is my whole code so im not sure what you mean by the code for the plot function. is there anything i need to include?

Comment: @fury sorry that took so long, i did it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely problem is that you are passing an integer to `plot()` when it expects an array.

At some point internally, it tries to get the length of the array and fails because you can't take the length of an integer.

At a guess, your code should be something like

```
MAX_REPS = 50

good_pts = []

for x in range (0,201):
    for y in range (0,201):
        for c in range(MAX_REPS):
            x, y = x - y + 100, x + y - 100

            if y <= 0:
                break
            elif x <= 0:
                good_pts.append((x, y))
                break
```

then plot the (x, y) points in `good_pts`.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that plot(i,j) is expecting i & j to be lists of coordinates? See what happens if you try:

```
 plot([i],[j])
```

Comment: when i do that it says: 'IndexError: list index out of range'

Comment: @arry - So, what is the API for plot()? I would imagine it is expecting something along the lines of 2 lists of the same length, or maybe a list of pairs (i.e. [[i,j]], where i & j are both numbers). Can you see any documentation for plot?